# Using $__timeFilter in grafana postgresql template query?

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I'm trying to create a template variable in Grafana-4.6.1, using a time filter:

SELECT value FROM table WHERE $__timeFilter(time_column).

Unfortunately this doesn't return any values, while it correctly returns a list of integers when I use it in a table query.

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also define which column is your "time" metric using the "$__time" macro.

```
SELECT
  $__time(time_column), 
  value
FROM table 
WHERE $__timeFilter(time_column)
```

If you don't want to see the time_column, then you can do a subquery:

```
SELECT value
FROM (
      SELECT
        $__time(time_column), 
        value
      FROM table
) a
WHERE $__timeFilter(time_column)
```

Comment: I don't think this is true.